# asp.ControlParamter control id conflict

Tags: asp.net

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddListPlayerPointSystems" Name="profileid" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddListCmty" Name="cmty" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$FormView3$pointsTextBox" Name="InsertPts" PropertyName="Text" Type="Decimal" />
```

I am having trouble understanding why in the first controlparameter i can call the dropdownbox id but not the textboxes id which is pointsTextBox. I am using a master page with an asp ajax tab container with multiple panels. If i take off the "ctl00$MainContent$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$FormView3$" i get a control not found but i dont know why this works for the other two controlparameters

**EDIT**
So I found a solution to my problem. Thanks to @TheGeekYouNeed and @JamesJ I understand why I would require the longer path name for that particular textbox (the drops were outside of the tabcontainer so the direct name worked). But I found that since I was assigning the value of that textbox via '<%# Bind("name", "{0:n}") %>' I was able to instead just use an asp:Parameter rather than the ControlParameter like so:

```
"<asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />"
```

Problem is that i don't quite understand how that all works.

Answer (score 0):

The ControlID for the pointsTextBox is not 'ct100$MainContent$TabContainer..etc...  on the server side.

Set the COntrolID in the code behind, so you can use FindControl("pointsTextBox") to get a reference to the textbox control.

You could do something like:

```
TextBox t = this.FindControl("pointsTextBox") as TextBox;
if(t != null)
{
    ddListPlayerPOintSystems.Add(new { COntrolID = t, Name = "InsertPts", PropertyName="Text", Type="Decimal"});
}
```

I haven't tested it, so I am not claiming the code is perfect, but the method you need to follow is illustrated here.

Comment: But it all works fine if i add the whole name, but the dropdowns don't seem to need it. And  'ct100$MainContent$TabContainer..etc' is the whole name after the page runs and asp changes the name. I'm just looking for an explanation as why the textbox requires the longer path name.

Comment: The `DropDownList` doesn't need it because it's directly accessible from the page, whereas the other control is likely nested in a databound control or something similar.